# Display duplicate records only once in yii2

Tags: database, yii2

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwDgG.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwDgG.png)

> **This is my code in controller**

```
public function actionInventorycopies()
    {
        $searchModel = new \app\models\LibBookCopySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        //$names = Yii::$app->$db->createCommand('SELECT  count(DISTINCT(book_id)) as id FROM lib_book_copy')
        //->queryAll();
        return $this->render('inventory_copies', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
            ]);

    }
```

This is my problem that , my book_id has two records and both are same . Now what i need is display the record only once . Both record of book_id and title should be shown once . I am doing my project in yii2 . So where should i chnage in controller .

Now i need to show only one book id and only one title . How can i do it ? Please help .

Comment: Try with `groupBy('book_id')`.

Comment: in your search model add  $query->groupBy(['book_id']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records are not really the same. They have different "Acc No".

Use `distinct` and remove "Acc No" from the query:

```
public function actionInventorycopies()
{
    $query = \app\models\LibBookCopy::find()->select(['book_id','title','quantity'])->distinct();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);
    return $this->render('inventory_copies', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

Also you should remove "Acc No" column from grid view.